# typescript export = module

Tags: intellij-idea, typescript

I see almost all definitions of libraries use the expression `export = module`. My IDE intellij idea of ​​an error in the syntax. For example, in express difinitions

```
declare module "express" {
   function express(): Express;

   module express {
      ...
      ...
      ...
   }


   export = express;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webstorm / IntelliJ-Idea only support TypeScript 0.8.x syntax at the moment. The `export = express;` syntax was introduced in typescript 0.9.0 which is why you are getting the syntax errors.

If you want to use Webstorm design time features, You can grab the old definitions from the 0.8.x branch on DefinitelyTyped : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/0.8

Alternatively you can use Visual studio 2012.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ 12 only supports TypeScript 0.8.

You can download the EAP version for IntelliJ from http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+13+EAP where they added support for TypeScript 0.9 features.